# Extracting specific info from a combined rss feed

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss, feed

I'm not very experienced with manipulating RSS feeds, please bear with me.

I have 2 feeds that I combined using RSSMIX here: http://www.rssmix.com/u/8225102/rss.xml. Within each item, in the description nodes, there is a line stating where the post originated from (site url and blog name).

What would be the best way to capture those two parts? These will be used in a custom list on a page I've built. Here's what I have so far:

```
<article>
<?php if ( function_exists( 'fetch_feed' ) ) { ?>
    <?php include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
        $feed = fetch_feed( 'http://www.rssmix.com/u/8225102/rss.xml' );   
        $limit = $feed -> get_item_quantity(7);
        $items = $feed -> get_items(0, $limit);

    if ( !$items ) {
        echo "problem";
    }
    else {
        //everything's cool
        foreach( $items as $item ){ ?>

        <div class="feed-post">
            <h2 class="post"><a class="link" href="<?php echo $item -> get_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $item -> get_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p class="date"><?php echo $item -> get_date( 'F j, Y' ); ?></p>
            <p class="blogname"><a href="The Blog Link">The Blog Name</a></p>
        </div>            
        <?php }
    } ?>
<?php } ?>

</article>
```

Granted, the line `<p class="blogname"><a href="The Blog Link">The Blog Name</a></p>` is where this content would go.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I know this was posted late in the week. Does anyone have any ideas?